# What is the best way to integrate FindBugs with Jdeveloper?

Tags: oracle-adf, jdeveloper, findbugs

I am a [Find bugs](http://findbugs.sourceforge.net/) fan and have used it before with `Intellij Idea` . It has a very nice plugin for `Intellij Idea`. Now I am using JDeveloper as it has the best support for `Oracle ADF` framework and my application is built on top of `ADF` . I want to find out what is the best possible way to integrate JDeveloper directly with FindBugs ? Are there any plugins ?

**Edit**: I have been through [this blog](https://blogs.oracle.com/shay/entry/findbugs_integration_with_jdeveloper) which describes how to integrate FindBugs into a build script for Ant but when I followed the steps mentioned there I see the following :

```
Buildfile: D:\Software\findbugs-2.0.2\findbugs.xml

init:

findbugs:
 [findbugs] Executing findbugs from ant task
 [findbugs] Running FindBugs...
 [findbugs] edu.umd.cs.findbugs.NoClassesFoundToAnalyzeException: No classes found to analyze in *C:\Oracle\Middleware\jdk160_24\jre\lib\resources.jar *C:\Oracle\Middleware\jdk160_24\jre\lib\rt.jar *C:\Oracle\Middleware\jdk160_24\jre\lib\jsse.jar *C:\Oracle\Middleware\jdk160_24\jre\lib\jce.jar *C:\Oracle\Middleware\jdk160_24\jre\lib\charsets.jar *C:\Oracle\Middleware\jdk160_24\jre\lib\ext\dnsns.jar *C:\Oracle\Middleware\jdk160_24\jre\lib\ext\localedata.jar *C:\Oracle\Middleware\jdk160_24\jre\lib\ext\sunjce_provider.jar *C:\Oracle\Middleware\jdk160_24\jre\lib\ext\sunmscapi.jar *C:\Oracle\Middleware\jdk160_24\jre\lib\ext\sunpkcs11.jar *D:\Software\findbugs-2.0.2\lib\annotations.jar *D:\Software\findbugs-2.0.2\lib\jsr305.jar 
 [findbugs]     at edu.umd.cs.findbugs.FindBugs2.execute(FindBugs2.java:273)
 [findbugs]     at edu.umd.cs.findbugs.FindBugs.runMain(FindBugs.java:391)
 [findbugs]     at edu.umd.cs.findbugs.FindBugs2.main(FindBugs2.java:1298)
 [findbugs] Java Result: 4

BUILD SUCCESSFUL
Total time: 4 seconds
```

I think it is not finding any files to analyze . But I have set the value of `basedir2` as the following :

```
${project.classpath}${java.path}${project.dir}${project.sourcepath}${target.class}${workspace.path}
```

Answer (score 0):

You know that you can debug ant scripts in jdev? 
You can step into each target, set breakpoints on targets and definitions. 
This would help you find out which parameters are passed to a target. You can even see the values of each variable like in a normal Java code.

Answer (score 0):

Note that in the blog the value set for basedir2 is ${project.dir}
Also make sure that before your run the findbugs you actually compile your project so the class files will be created in the right directory.

Comment: Initially I put just ${project.dir}. It was showing the same error message . So I appended other paths to the basedir2 property but still the problem isn't resolved.